# How to set an output of SQL query as a column in the table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `tabl` with column `colmn`.
I want to assign an output of a particular query to `colmn` in `tabl`.

I am writing this as follows:

```
UPDATE tabl SET colmn = (SELECT x FROM another_tabl);
```

But I get an error as:

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Do I explicitly need to take a join if I know that the order of the column I am trying to attach is fixed?

Comment: Only one column is allowed using subquery.so you cannot able to use select * in subquery

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The `UPDATE` statement as you wrote it sets column `colmn` of `tabl` to a single value (in every row). If this is your intention then change subquery to return exactly that value? Or did you intend to set `colmn` to a corresponding `x` value from `another_tabl` based on some correlation condition? Then use a `UPDATE ... FROM ...`variant.

Comment: @rpy I want to attach a column from `tableX` to `tableY` without any condition because I already know that `tableX` and `tableY` contains same number of rows. Coming from R and Python dataframes background, I am having a hard time digesting that one must take a join of two tables on some column in order to simply attach a column from one table to another. What if both of the table contain only one column each, I don't understand how would I achieve it then.

Comment: @Sangram: Please, read up about underlying logic of SQL. There is now ay beside writing an explicit "ORDER BY" to "know" the order of the rows. The processing is free do present you the rows in any order. If you have a "natural" order in mind (as ou state "the order is fixed") then you need to make it explicit. (e.g. add a rownum colum). But, then still you have to declare which row from table B is to be related to a given row from table A. This is what the join condition is for.  The downside is with pure mysql there is no immediate support for accessing somethng like a rownum property.

Comment: @Sangram: or to express it with programming terms:  a table in SQL is a SET of rows not an ARRAY with implicit ordering of elements.

Comment: @rpy: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tabl SET colmn = (SELECT colname FROM another_tabl where some condition order by colname limit 1);
```

This subquery should return only one Row

Comment: Not it wont , some condition can have more than one row.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM another_table");
$stmt1->execute($array_data1);
$result_data1 = $stmt1->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
foreach( $result_data1 as $res ) {
    //here write your update query like 
    UPDATE tabl SET colmn = $res['colmn_name_of_another_table'] 
}
```